# How could the bug in the below C# code be fixed by only changing 1 or 2 lines of code?

Tags: c#, arrays, debugging

I'm trying to solve the below problem in C# which I was unable to answer within the time limit during a technical interview.

- The provided code contains a bug and it can only be fixed by amending 2 lines of code at most.
- The function takes 2 integer arrays as parameters.
- All integers within both parameters will always be positive integers.
- There may be multiple occurrences of the same integer in each array parameter.
- The function should return the lowest positive integer that exists in both arrays.
- The function should return `-1` if no such integer exists

```
public int test(int[] A, int[] B)
{
    int m = A.Length;
    int n = B.Length;
    Array.Sort(A);
    Array.Sort(B);

    int i = 0;
    for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
    {
        if (i < n - 1 && B[i] < A[k])
            i += 1;
        if (A[k] == B[i])
            return A[k];
    }

    return -1;
}
```

I'm struggling to come up with a solution that only amends 1-2 lines of code.  I thought I could replace `i += 1;` with  `i += 1; k = 0;` but this is obviously adding a new line.

The original code will work for some inputs but not something like the below example because we don't want to increase `k` when `B[i] < A[k]`:

```
int[] A = { 3, 4, 5, 6 };
int[] B = { 2, 2, 2, 3 ,5 };
```

Comment: why not replacing `if(i < n - 1 && ...)` with `while(...)`?

Answer (score 0):

Considering you can only amend the code and not add new lines to it, I believe the following should be working:

```
public int test(int[] A, int[] B)
{
  int m = A.Length;
  int n = B.Length;
  Array.Sort(A);
  Array.Sort(B);

  int i = 0;
  for (int k = 0; k < m; k++)
  {
    while (i < n - 1 && B[i] < A[k])
    {
      i += 1;
    }
    if (A[k] == B[i])
      return A[k];
  }
  return -1;
}
```

What changed is that the **if** that was checking for **i** is now a **while**

It's not exactly the prettiest code, but since those are the requirements...